# ~/.profile is not loaded when using SSH (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ruby, .bash-profile, .profile

*Edited to reflect the problem I really wanted to solve:*

I need to set up my ruby environment so I can deploy via Capistrano.

```
export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I put these in ~deploy/.profile, but when I ssh in, they aren't being run. Ideas?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

---

The original question was:

*When I ssh into another account at localhost, it doesn't load my .profile. How can I force ssh to load it? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.*

Answer (score 22):

You may explicitly specify that you want to start an interactive login shell:

```
 ssh user@host bash --login -i
```

The *"role"* of `~/.profile` (or ~./bash_profile) and `.bashrc` for ssh have some other files,
(see `man ssh` for details):

> ~/.ssh/environment
>
> Contains additional definitions for environment variables; see ENVIRONMENT, above.
>
> ~/.ssh/rc
>
> Commands in this file are executed by ssh when the user logs in, just before the user's shell (or command) is started.  See the sshd(8) manual page for more information.

Comment: “You may” is often not true, because ssh is being run by some other tool (continuous delivery) and the command can't be easily changed.

Comment: This doesn't work if the user on the remote machine has a restricted shell.

Answer (score 12):

`.profile` is only loaded for login shells, which an ssh session is not (by default). If you want something to run on startup for all interactive shells, put it in `.bashrc` instead (or `.zshrc` or whatever your shell uses).

Also, if you just want to log into another account on the local machine, ssh is probably overkill. You might want to use `su` or something instead.

Comment: It seems `.bashrc` is not loaded either.

Comment: This is incorrect. It **is** a login shell. From the man page: "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell."

Comment: ~/.zshenv works for me. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/sh-startup-files-over-ssh/

Comment: When ssh is given a command to run, it defaults to *not* allocate a tty and then the shell is not “interactive” either.

Comment: Be careful about `.zshenv`, see the `PATH` caveats mentioned here: https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/StartupFiles/zshenv

Answer (score 7):

Using bash should result in reading `~/.bashrc`. The following might help with ksh and sh (bash in sh mode), or when your `~/.bashrc` is not executed during login.

The sshd consults `~/.ssh/environment` (check sshd_config(5) for permissions) and `~/.ssh/sshrc` or `~/.ssh/rc`. This gives the possibility to setup `ENV=~/.profile` or `BASH_ENV=~/.profile` and `SSH_LOGIN=Y`

In `~/.profile` I've the following layout (Replace `ENV` with `BASH_ENV` when using bash):

```
if [[ -n $SSH_LOGIN || -z $ENV ]]; then
     # Put here login initialization code
     unset SSH_LOGIN
     ENV=~/.profile
fi
 # Put here code thats get executed with each ksh/sh invocation
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably have a `~/.bash_profile`, which overrides `~/.profile`.

Comment: Simplest explanation. Installed some package, and colors disappeared. Turns out a rogue `.bash_profile` appeared and stole my colors

Answer (score 1):

Bash reads `~/.profile` only when it is a login shell and `~/.bash.bashrc` only if it has a terminal, neither of which is true by default when invoking a command with ssh. However, there are several other options to set environment, on the server, all unfortunately depending on the system setup:

- Zsh reads `~/.zshenv` even in this case; there is no corresponding config file for bash though.
- If the `PermitUserEnvironment` option is on in `/etc/sshd_config`, ssh will read `~/.ssh/environment`. Unfortunately this option defaults to off.
- If the `pam_env.so` is called with `user_readenv=1` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, it will read `~/.pam_environment`. While it is not default of the module, it *is called that way at least in Ubuntu*.
- If all else fails, you can put a `command=` directive in the authorized keys file calling a wrapper script that sets the environment and executes the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` at the end (I the command is one for shell, so eval is appropriate here, but I am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access then you can put environment variables in `/etc/environment`. That way, they are set no matter what shell or login type you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh localhost 'echo $MyEnv'
```

ssh with command will try to source $BASH_ENV according to gnu bash manual
because it is a non-interactive shell I think

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the accepted answer?

Comment: @DarkDiamond This particular answer might not be much help, but note that there is no accepted answer. So this may in fact be better than the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it isn't clear if you're ssh-ing into the deploy user's account and running commands:

```
ssh deploy@myhost
```

... or if you're using ssh to run a command as the deploy user:

```
ssh deploy@myhost my-command-to-run
```

If I am logged into a host and:

```
earl@myhost:~$ echo $PATH
/home/earl/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

It shows `/home/earl/bin` at the beginning of my `PATH` because I set it in my `~/.profile` file.

If I ssh to another user on the same machine:

```
earl@myhost:~$ ssh deploy@myhost
deploy@myhost:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

The login is now using the `PATH` setting for the `deploy` user because I'm using an interactive ssh login shell. It's getting the PATH setting from deploy's `~/.profile` file, which doesn't contain `/home/earl/bin`.

However, if I just typed:

```
earl@myhost:~$ ssh deploy@myhost ./run-commands.sh
```

ssh is going to ssh into the `deploy` user's account on the same host and run the `deploy` user's `./run-commands.sh` script, but ssh will not be using a login shell and none of the environment settings in the `deploy` user's `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` files will be executed because ssh is just running a command, it isn't starting a shell.

If you're trying to use ssh interactively, and `.profile` isn't getting run, you probably set the shell for `deploy` to a shell that doesn't exist or a shell that doesn't use `.profile` files. Try:

```
earl@myhost:~$ ssh deploy@myhost
deploy@myhost:~$ ps -p $$
```

... to find out what shell the `deploy` user is using.

If you're trying to use ssh to run a command, create a `run-commands.sh` shell script, add:

```
source ~/.profile
```

... to the beginning of the shell script, followed by the commands you want to run, and then `ssh deploy@myhost ./run-commands.sh` should work.