# Fake user on SSH server restricted to using only some commands

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to make a fake user (a user that can be logged on from SSH but does not exist on the system) that has some restrictions (for example they can only use one command and when they do another command will be executed too). Is there a way to achieve this? I cannot find a way to make a fake user on openssh-server, let alone the restriction part.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? ([XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Comment: A ssh proxy that starts another ssh in it if connected to a certain username and types a certain command.

Comment: [The link here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8257), although it’s an older page, explains a lot of useful info about configuring SSH, including restricting a client to a fixed set of commands.

Answer (score 1):

It's common for SSH servers in Linux to integrate with the system and not to introduce another layer of users. It's not like Samba nor FTP, where such layer of Samba-specific or FTP-specific users exists. I guess it's a non-trivial task to make `sshd` from OpenSSH define an independent set of users (but maybe another answer will surprise me).

Maybe your intention to make a fake user stems from the fact you are not root on the SSH server and you cannot create a real user there. If so, this is what you can do anyway<sup>1</sup>:

See `man 5 authorized_keys` where it describes the format. In my Debian the manual states [emphasis mine]:

> `AuthorizedKeysFile` specifies the files containing public keys for public key authentication; if this option is not specified, the default is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`. Each line of the file contains one key (empty lines and lines starting with a ‘#’ are ignored as comments). Public keys consist of the following space-separated fields: options, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment. The options field is optional. […]
>
> The options (if present) consist of comma-separated option specifications.  No spaces are permitted, except within double quotes.  The following option specifications are supported (note that option keywords are case-insensitive):
>
> […]
>
> `command="command"`
> **Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used for authentication. The command supplied by the user (if any) is ignored.** The command is run on a pty if the client requests a pty; otherwise it is run without a tty. If an 8-bit clean channel is required, one must not request a pty or should specify `no-pty`. A quote may be included in the command by quoting it with a backslash.
>
> **This option might be useful to restrict certain public keys to perform just a specific operation. An example might be a key that permits remote backups but nothing else.** Note that the client may specify TCP and/or X11 forwarding unless they are explicitly prohibited, e.g. using the `restrict` key option.
>
> […]

This way, as a regular user, you can allow somebody else (from now on: a guest) to log in *as you* and to run one specific command *as you* automatically. Simply register their public key in your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server, using the `command="command"` option.

The command may be a custom program or a script that allows the guest to choose a task from a list, or to type a keyword to choose a task; or to type an "inner" command that will be validated and allowed or disallowed; the program will then execute something accordingly. It's up to you what the command/program/script is.

Note from the point of view of the SSH server and its admins the guest *is* you. It's your account that runs the command and if your custom program or script allows the guest to run an arbitrary command somehow (e.g. by spawning a shell first somehow) then it will be as if *you* run the command.

Also keep in mind the command is run in a non-interactive shell. It will be your shell (the one you pick with `chsh`) with your configuration. The shell may source some files (see [how Bash behaves](https://superuser.com/a/1616143/432690)), so make sure they are safe to be sourced when the guest connects.

The manual states that "the command supplied by the user (if any) is ignored". Nevertheless in my tests the forced executable could get it from its environment, the variable is named `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`. This means you can allow the guest to pass some information (e.g. options) directly in their invocation of `ssh`; on the server side your program will retrieve it from the variable. In a shell code [don't `eval` the variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and [don't use `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` unquoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/108618), unless you verify its safety or sanitize it first.

An example line in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` that allows the owner of a specific key to see the output of `df -h` looks like this:

```
command="df -h",no-pty ssh-rsa AAA…(public key here)…
```

(For the description of `no-pty` see `man 5 authorized_keys`. There are other options you may find useful.) Now whoever uses this specific key to connect to the server (using your login) will see the output of `df -h` and will get disconnected.

---

<sup>1</sup> Probably. The SSH server may be configured to deny various things.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at deploying an SSH honeypot. Basically a dummy server which looks vulnerable but has no real access to anything. Everything is logged and you can restrict access to commands.

Setting one up is not difficult and there are many resources online for instructions on how to deploy one. It might be a little long for an answer on here though!

**EDIT :** Superuser isn't really a place for recommendations, but this appears to be we well used one with many tutorials online: https://github.com/cowrie/cowrie
From the README:

Choose to run as an emulated shell (default):

- Fake filesystem with the ability to add/remove files. A full fake
  filesystem resembling a Debian 5.0 installation is included
- Possibility of adding fake file contents so the attacker can cat
  files such as /etc/passwd. Only minimal file contents are included
- Cowrie saves files downloaded with wget/curl or uploaded with SFTP
  and scp for later inspection

Comment: @soshimee - Questions seeking recommendations are out of scope and will be closed.