# determining what a linux command is doing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh

When I SSH into a machine I can run a particular command (let's say `mycommand`) on that machine's bash terminal without issue. BUT when I try to do `ssh localhost 'mycommand'` I get an "unknown command" error.

Maybe the command is defined in my .bashrc file as an alias but I checked and it isn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: `which mycommand` should show where the executable is. Sounds like it's in your current path, but not in the path given to ssh shells

Comment: `type mycommand` is better than `which mycommand`, because the former will also look at builtins, functions, and aliases.

Comment: Maybe you alter your `PATH` in `~/.bashrc` and this act is crucial for `mycommand` to be found. See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1616143/432690). Some part of your `~/.bashrc` may be omitted in a non-interactive shell started by the SSH server after you `ssh localhost 'mycommand'`.